# Google maps standard on Android phone?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This may be a stupid question, but here it goes. Is Google Maps a standard (and pre-installed) application on every android phone? I am writing a map application and using a mapview to plot several points near a given zip code. I got that working. If Google maps is pre-installed on every phone, then i can just theoretically send Google maps my two points and it will take care of the rest, correct? Or will i have to go old school and program all driving directions myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you distributing your application?  If you are distributing it via the official Android Market, its pretty safe to assume Google Maps will be present.  Any device without Google Maps, probably doesn't have Google's seal of approval and won't have the market app either.

Comment: i will definitely be distributing the app via android market and it will only be for phones at this time.

Comment: @sexitrainer Then honestly, I wouldn't worry about it.  Its not worth tearing your hair out to appease 1% of your market when the other 99% want you to spend your time adding new features or making improvements.

Answer (score 1):

MapView works on all Android phones as far as I'm aware.

But some other features are NOT included on devices that haven't got the Google seal of approval (e.g. 10" tablets prior to Honeycomb):

- The Google Maps application
- The Geocoder class (for converting between place names and latitude/longitude locations)

To be clear - there are devices out there where the MapView user interface element works, but Google Maps itself (the separate application) is not present. And when that app is missing, some of the mapping features in the OS are also scaled back (I know Geocoder is, possibly others).

If you can't use Google Maps for your application, look at OpenStreetMap as there are libraries to render OSMs in Android apps, and that'll work on anything. See here:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android

Android is open-source and includes the core stuff, but some features are Google's proprietary code, and are not part of the Android open source project. So on devices that only use the open-source features, you won't get everything.

Having said all that, I would expect the vast majority of Android devices DO include what you need. If you need to target Android phones without the Google code on them, I suggest you buy one - as they're usually crap they're usually cheap!

Btw, when you send those directions to Google Maps, you use a URL (intent) so if Maps is present it'll pick it up, but if not it'll go to the web so likely to work on some devices anyway.

I suspect this isn't much of an issue for you.

Comment: Everything you've said is correct, except he probably doesn't even need to worry about it if he is distributing his app through the market.  All those crappy tablets don't have the market app either.

Comment: That's not really true. Many of the crappy tablets are being hacked. I have a tablet here that has the Market on it (unofficially) but is still missing the Geocoder, despite the Maps application being present. Though even if Geocoder is missing, I imagine the app could use the Google Maps API directly to get the job done.

Comment: I have to imagine the population of hacked, crappy, tablets is way too small for a developer to worry about.  Especially considering that demographic is mostly Android fanatics who will upgrade to honeycomb tablets anyways?

Comment: @dbyrne To a degree, but even some of the custom ROMs are missing the Geocoder functionality which is pretty valuable for doing mapping. In the UK you can buy a non-Google Android tablet 10" for about USD300, compared to $800 for the Xoom, so bargain-hunters will buy them as well as the techs, but I'm sure it will be a minority of the market

Comment: At this time, I want my app ONLY on phones. that's why i had asked my question. I don't care about tablets.

Comment: I'd expect the percentage of Android phones with Google Maps to be pretty near 100%, so I expect you'll be just fine

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps is pre-installed on just about every current version of Android. If it's not 100% it's pretty close. You can see where else Maps can be run [here](http://www.google.com/mobile/maps/).

Answer (score 0):

You can launch an Intent that will open Google Maps. Check out the Intent [list](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) for Google Apps.